# Flask-SocketIO trouble with sid and namespaces

Tags: python, sockets, flask, flask-socketio

Flask-SocketIO is giving me some trouble. I am trying to initialize private chat rooms with the following code:

```
@socketio.on('join', namespace='/join')
def on_join(receiver_name):
    username = session['username']
    join_room(receiver_name)  # start a chat room with the receiver's username
    send(username + ' is now connected.', room=receiver_name)
```

Unfortunately, I am getting errors such as `AttributeError: 'Request' object has no attribute 'sid'`. Even when I specifically specify `request.sid` I get an error. When I plug in something random for the `sid` field in `join_room`, I then get a namespace error. I have ensured that I am importing everything necessary etc.

Here is the specific error message.

```
[2017-10-04 10:02:48,297] ERROR in app: Exception on /start_chat [POST]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1982, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1614, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1517, in handle_user_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/_compat.py", line 33, in reraise
    raise value
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1612, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1598, in dispatch_request
    return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
  File "/Users/agaidis/Desktop/challenge-backend-master/challenge-eng-base-master/backend-python/app.py", line 132, in start_chat
    on_join(friend_username)
  File "/Users/agaidis/Desktop/challenge-backend-master/challenge-eng-base-master/backend-python/app.py", line 152, in on_join
    join_room(receiver_name)  # start a chat room with the receiver's username
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask_socketio/__init__.py", line 756, in join_room
    sid = sid or flask.request.sid
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/werkzeug/local.py", line 347, in __getattr__
    return getattr(self._get_current_object(), name)
AttributeError: 'Request' object has no attribute 'sid'
127.0.0.1 - - [04/Oct/2017 10:02:48] "POST /start_chat HTTP/1.1" 500 -
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are invoking the `on_join()` function yourself from an HTTP route. That's not how this is supposed to work. The Socket.IO events are invoked when the client calls `emit()` on that event. The `request.sid` variable only exists in the context of a Socket.IO event handler, that will not be present in an HTTP handler.

Based on your stack trace, I think you need to change the `start_chat` route from HTTP to Socket.IO. The client will need to request to join the chat by making an `emit()` call instead of sending an HTTP request.

Comment: Thank you! I am a noob to Flask and Socket.IO. In order to instantiate multiple rooms, clients open up new socket connections in the client-side code, correct?  The web-page they see will be the normal HTML with whatever stuff is specific to their open socket?

Comment: You can associate a single client connection with multiple rooms, no need to create multiple connections. It is totally okay to call `join_room()` multiple times for the same client.